# YouTube video viewer program

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use the Youtube viewer program on someone's YouTube videos. The source code of this program can be found on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/MShawon/YouTube-Viewer).

There is a problem in the import statements, though.

In the `YouTube viewer -> youtubeviewer -> download_driver.py` file, [so this page](https://github.com/MShawon/YouTube-Viewer/blob/master/youtubeviewer/download_driver.py), there is an import statement.

```py
import undetected_chromedriver._compat as uc
```

At first when I tried to run this program, the following error pops up:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'undetected_chromedriver'
```

I eventually installed it using the `python3 -m pip install undetected_chromedriver` command. Everything ran smoothly until the statement above. The command prompt popped up the following error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\14725\YouTube-Viewer\youtube_viewer.py", line 42, in <module>
    from youtubeviewer.download_driver import *
  File "C:\Users\14725\YouTube-Viewer\youtubeviewer\download_driver.py", line 29, in <module>
    import undetected_chromedriver._compat as uc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'undetected_chromedriver._compat'
```

I checked again if I had installed the module by using the `python3 -m pip install undetected_chromedriver` command. The following messages popped up:

```
Requirement already satisfied: undetected_chromedriver in c:\users\14725\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\14725\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from undetected_chromedriver) (2.28.0)
Requirement already satisfied: selenium>=4.0.0 in c:\users\14725\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from undetected_chromedriver) (4.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: websockets in c:\users\14725\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from undetected_chromedriver) (10.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2021.10.8 in c:\users\14725\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from selenium>=4.0.0->undetected_chromedriver) (2022.5.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: trio~=0.17 in c:\users\14725\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from selenium>=4.0.0->undetected_chromedriver) (0.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3[socks]~=1.26 in c:\users\14725\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from selenium>=4.0.0->undetected_chromedriver) (1.26.9)
Requirement already satisfied: trio-websocket~=0.9 in c:\users\14725\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from selenium>=4.0.0->undetected_chromedriver) (0.9.2)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in c:\users\14725\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from requests->undetected_chromedriver) (2.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\14725\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from requests->undetected_chromedriver) (3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.14 in c:\users\14725\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from trio~=0.17->selenium>=4.0.0->undetected_chromedriver) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: sniffio in c:\users\14725\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from trio~=0.17->selenium>=4.0.0->undetected_chromedriver) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: sortedcontainers in c:\users\14725\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from trio~=0.17->selenium>=4.0.0->undetected_chromedriver) (2.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: async-generator>=1.9 in c:\users\14725\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from trio~=0.17->selenium>=4.0.0->undetected_chromedriver) (1.10)
Requirement already satisfied: outcome in c:\users\14725\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from trio~=0.17->selenium>=4.0.0->undetected_chromedriver) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=19.2.0 in c:\users\14725\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from trio~=0.17->selenium>=4.0.0->undetected_chromedriver) (21.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: exceptiongroup>=1.0.0rc9 in c:\users\14725\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from trio~=0.17->selenium>=4.0.0->undetected_chromedriver) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wsproto>=0.14 in c:\users\14725\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from trio-websocket~=0.9->selenium>=4.0.0->undetected_chromedriver) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: PySocks!=1.5.7,<2.0,>=1.5.6 in c:\users\14725\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from urllib3[socks]~=1.26->selenium>=4.0.0->undetected_chromedriver) (1.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\14725\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from cffi>=1.14->trio~=0.17->selenium>=4.0.0->undetected_chromedriver) (2.21)
Requirement already satisfied: h11<1,>=0.9.0 in c:\users\14725\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from wsproto>=0.14->trio-websocket~=0.9->selenium>=4.0.0->undetected_chromedriver) (0.14.0)
```

Which I think these have indicated that I have the module installed. What should I do to run this program? Have I missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was [an important update of `undetected_chromedriver` recently](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/blob/bf7dcf8b5713020de7454844fb80036b8c456503/README.md#340). I recommend you to install the latest known stable version with:

```
pip install undetected-chromedriver==3.2.1
```